# Will I be granted a Schengen visa if my bank statements are not yet three months old?

Tags: schengen, proof-provenance-of-funds, zimbabwean-citizens

I'm from Zimbabwe.

Is it necessary for me to print for a proof of payment of travelling medical insurance in my email and add it in my application document for Schengen visa to Germany?

I did not have a bank account but have opened one three days ago and deposited $50.

Is it OK to continue depositing $50 and will they grant me the visa?

Comment: [This advice](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab) is about UK visas, not Schengen, but the same concepts apply. You should read it carefully. In short, they're looking for sufficient funds for your trip (several times over what it will cost) and a longstanding stable pattern of deposits and savings. A brand new account with $50 here and there will raise suspicion. Nobody can really predict whether your visa will be issued, but those bank statements are unlikely to work in your favor.

Answer (score 4):

- Tourist travel in Europe can easily cost USD 50 a day or or more if you are a typical tourist. That doesn't count the flight to Europe. Your trip will probably cost you several thousand USD.
- The visa officials want to see if you can *reasonably* afford that much. That doesn't just mean you need enough money in the bank account, you also need a *steady* income to explain where the money came from and why you will spend it on a holiday.

Your disposable income needs to be **much** higher than USD 50.